# Viewing the error message in a Python UDF

Tags: python, regex, user-defined-functions, apache-pig

I'm looking for best practices on debugging Python UDFs.

I can't get this UDF to run and I can't get an error message of value to appear in the logs.

This function takes a date of the format 'DD-MON-YY' as input ('01-JAN-2013', for example) and returns the week of the year that day occurred as output (For '01-JAN-2013', that would be the zeroth week of the year, so the return value would be 0).

```
@outputSchema("week_number:int")
def week_from_date(input_date):
    date_to_match = re.match('(\d{2}).?([A-Za-z]{3}).?(\d{4})', input_date)
    if date_to_match:
        day, month, year = date_to_match.group(1), date_to_match.group(2), date_to_match.group(3)        
        import time
        from time import gmtime, strftime
        d = time.strptime("%s %s %s" % (day, month, year), "%d %b %Y")
       return int(strftime("%U", d))
    else:
            return -1
```

I'm receiving this error: `Backend error : Error executing function`

Is there anyway to get a more descriptive error message? What are the best practices for debugging Python UDFs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, I see indentation mistakes that can be the source of the issue (although it can be related to your post and not the original code).

However, you can see a more detailed error stack from two sources:
- Pig logs, usually in a text file (ex: pig_1388770791476.log);
- Hadoop job tracker: by clicking on the related job and then on the killed task, you can see errors and the corresponding stack.

Comment: Any idea where this would be when running pig in Local Mode? The Pig log contains only a generic error message like the one I have in the post above.

Comment: The log file is supposed to be dumped in your cwd, e.g. the location from where you launched grunt. You can reach your jobtracker admin platform using your jobtracker ip and port. If in local, and with default port, that should be: http://127.0.0.1:50030/jobtracker.jsp